# How can i prevent label in div overlapping another div content on a table td

Tags: html, css

```
    <table>
<thead>
  <th>Item</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div style="display:inline-block;width:25%">
      <label style="display:block">abcdefghijklmnop</label>
      <input type="checkbox">
      </div>
      <div style="display:inline-block;width:25%">
      <label style="display:block">abcdefghijklmnop</label>
      <input type="checkbox">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I want it to auto jump to next line if the label text overflow. I no want the label to be hidden or using ellipsis.

Note: In my case, i will loop the div content in the same row td. I want to break the word to next line in full size of browser or browser resized to smaller.

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for having too less reputation to post a comment.

But have you checked out Bootstrap tables? 
It not only solves your problem,  but is a good step in moving towards simple web development.

Bootstrap takes care of everything and allows us to make neat and clean tables with very little code from our side.

If at all you need to further style your table, you can add styling OVER the bootstrap styled table.

Check out the following simple tutorial where you can also try it out online.

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tables.asp

To prove how simple it is,

- I have pasted my code into a simple HTML page.
- Added bootstrap.

And voila! Your issue is solved in the example given below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
      <th>Item</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>
              <label>abcdefghijklmnop</label>
          </div>
          <div>
              <input type="checkbox">
          </div>
           <div>
              <label>abcdefghijklmnop</label>
           </div>
           <div>
              <input type="checkbox">
           </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
      <th>Item</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td> <label>abcdefghijklmnop</label> </td>
        <td> <input type="checkbox"> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> <label>abcdefghijklmnop</label> </td>
        <td> <input type="checkbox"> </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

I am still confused on what you wanted, so I have included 2 approaches.

Comment: i am using bootstrap table, it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Bootstrap will solve your issue and according to me IS the way a web developer must take.
I have updated my answer to prove my point, please check it out.
Cheers!

Comment: But, when resize the browser then it will overlapped as well.

Comment: You must remove your sytling for that. You styling given in the "style" tag is the reason for it.
I have updated my answer. Please check it out and choose the one out of the two tables I have supplied.
Let me know if you need further help

Comment: I want my checkbox below the label, that's why i am doing that.

Comment: In that case, you must place the label and the checkbox in two different divs. I have edited my answer again.     I wish to clarify again that if a responsive webpage is your requirement, then Bootstrap IS the best option. I speak from few years of experience. You shouldn't end up wasting precious time. Use standard high quality CSS libraries for simple requirements. Use plain CSS only for heavily customized needs. Please do accept the answer if this latest update has solved your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try Float:right;

```
<table>
<thead>
<th>Item</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
  <div style="display:inline-block;width:25%">
  <label style="display:block">abcdefghijklmnop</label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  </div>
  <div style="display:inline-block;width:10%; float:right;">
  <label style="display:block">abcdefghijklmnop</label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  </div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `word-wrap: break-word` for your `label` tag.
The word-wrap property allows long words to be able to be broken and wrap onto the next line. break-word allows unbreakable words to be broken

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Item</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div style="display:inline-block;width:25%">
          <label style="display:block;word-wrap: break-word;">abcdefghijklmnop</label>
          <input type="checkbox">
        </div>
        <div style="display:inline-block;width:10%">
          <label style="display:block;word-wrap: break-word;">abcdefghijklmnop</label>
          <input type="checkbox">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[MDN web docs word-wrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/word-wrap)